# SSRS parameter Datatypes

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

Is there a way a parameter can take both int type and varchar type of values? I have a search field whose value is being passed in as a parameter and that value can be either a varchar or an int value. I know I can sort it out by have two different parameter field one which is varchar and the other int.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. A varchar takes either characters or integers and can be sorted.  Are you looking to sort the parameter one way if it's strictly an integer and the other if it has alpha characters?

Comment: So I have a field that acts a filter in my application. This field can filter either by Year(4 digit year, int) or by Name(varchar). My report takes the data entered in this field as a parameter and then runs the report according to what the filter criteria is.  I declared it as a parameter that takes a Text value but then I get an error saying cannot convert a varchar into an int type.

Comment: Are you also using SSRS to create the report? What I'm thinking is you could set two parameters, both of which could accept null. You could then use an Iif statement to set the parameter based on the filter and push that parameter to propagate the report.

Comment: I think you can have one varchar parameter then use ISNUMERIC to determine of you should parse it as a string or INT. Is your filtering in the report or the SQL?

Comment: I am using SSRS to create the report. I finally am having two parameters each of which takes NULL values and picking and choosing the right filter depending on the value in the search field. Also the filtering is happening in the report and not the sql. Thanks for your suggestions!